# How do I create custom savestate files in PCSX2 0.9.7 using the "Other..." option?

Tags: emulation, pcsx2

I'd like to be able to use the "Other" option when creating savestates in PCSX2, but whenever I try I get the following message:

> If this were hooked up, it would save a savestate file.

I'm guessing this probably means that the feature was never fully built into the emulator software, however I've been unable to find anything online that states one way or the other.  On the off chance it should be working and I'm simply doing something wrong, I wanted to ask about it here.

Can this feature be used, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

The current version of PCSX2 (1.0.0) can save Savestates. Following [the wiki](http://wiki.pcsx2.net/index.php?title=Savestate), you can create a savestate by pressing F1 and load a savestate by pressing F3. To switch between the slots, you can use F2 or Shift + F2.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @vertigoelectric sorry, I misunderstood your question then.

Comment: Not to worry.  I know I can use the savestate slots. However there is an option called "Other" and I want to know how to get that to work.  The wiki does not discuss this.

Comment: @vertigoelectric What is your reason for wanting to use it, then, if not to make a savestate?

Comment: You misunderstand.  The option says "it would save a savestate file", which leads me to believe that I could make a savestate using a custom filename rather than relying on their built in slots.  That is what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it, but to me this sounds like it's an entry point for a plugin. So you could essentially write your own savestate plugin, then pick that option to actually call it. There's no way for you to input additional parameters or anything like that using that option.